# Right in front of relative clause, what prepositions are frequently used?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, relative-clauses

I recently learned relative clause with preposition.

After some of my "English Deep learning process" so to speak, I got a mere sense that only few prepositions such as "in, on, at" are located at in front of relative clause frequently.

e.g.

> Some systems on which programs require high performance should be managed well.

Conversely, I've almost never seen prepositions like "behind, above, below" are located at in front of relative clause,
although sentences like

> The professor behind whom I sat is teaching students in *** university.

I usually saw it in this way.

> the professor who I sat behind is teaching students in *** university.

What prepositions are mostly used with relative clause and why this discrimination between prepositions happens?

Thank you!

Comment: This question is tricky because it is a question that is part of the implicit knowledge of most native English speakers, but I've never seen it elucidated as a formal rule or given it active thought that it is a rule.

Comment: According to 'traditional' standards of English grammar, _behind whom I sat_ would be regarded as the correct version. However, many people would regard that as too formal for everyday speech and would find _who I sat behind_ perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @KateBunting There’s no proscription against stranding preps in traditional grammar though, so long as they don’t occur at the end of a sentence.

Comment: Results may well be skewed by weight of relative clause: _The professor behind whom the thirty-eight girls from the famous prep school in Baden-Wurttemberg sat is teaching students in *** university._

Comment: English learners are always asking for rules or guidelines like this, but unfortunately English is woefully short of them. You just have to learn them by experience.